# Keeping Material UI tabs and React Router in sync

Tags: reactjs, react-router, material-ui

Is there a non hacky way to keep Material UI tabs and React router in sync?

Basically, I want to change the URL when the user clicks on a tab [1] and the tabs should change automatically when the user navigates to a different page with a non-tab link or button, and of course on direct access [2] and page refresh too.

Also, it would be nice to have the react router's *non exact* feature too, so the `/foo` tab should be active both for `/foo` and `/foo/bar/1`.

[1] Other SO answers recommend using the history api directly, is that a good practice with react-router?

[2] I'm not sure what it's called, I meant when the user loads for example `/foo` directly instead of loading `/` and then navigating to `/foo` by a tab or link

---

**Edit:**

I created a wrapper component which does the job, but with a few problems:

```
class CustomTabs extends React.PureComponent {
    constructor() {
        super();

        this.state = {
            activeTab: 0
        }
    }

    setActiveTab(id) {
        this.setState({
            activeTab: id
        });
        return null;
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.props.children.map((tab,index) => {
                    return (
                        <Route
                            key={index}
                            path={tab.props.path||"/"}
                            exact={tab.props.exact||false}
                            render={() => this.setActiveTab(index)}
                        />
                    );
                })}
                <Tabs
                    style={{height: '64px'}}
                    contentContainerStyle={{height: '100%'}}
                    tabItemContainerStyle={{height: '100%'}}
                    value={this.state.activeTab}
                >
                    {this.props.children.map((tab,index) => {
                        return (
                            <Tab
                                key={index}
                                value={index}
                                label={tab.props.label||""}
                                style={{paddingLeft: '10px', paddingRight: '10px', height: '64px'}}
                                onActive={() => {
                                    this.props.history.push(tab.props.path||"/")
                                }}
                            />
                        );
                    })}
                </Tabs>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

And I'm using it like this:

```
<AppBar title="Title" showMenuIconButton={false}>
    <CustomTabs history={this.props.history}>
        <Tab label="Home" path="/" exact/>
        <Tab label="Foo" path="/foo"/>
        <Tab label="Bar" path="/bar"/>
    </CustomTabs>
</AppBar>
```

But:

- I get this warning in my console:

> Warning: setState(...): Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render` or another component's constructor). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state; constructor side-effects are an anti-pattern, but can be moved to `componentWillMount`.

I think it's because I set the state immediately after `render()` is called - because of `Route.render`, but I have no idea how to solve this.

- The tab changing animations are lost: http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/tabs

---

**Edit #2**

I finally solved everything, but in a bit hacky way.

```
class CustomTabsImpl extends PureComponent {
    constructor() {
        super();

        this.state = {
            activeTab: 0
        }
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        this.state.activeTab = this.pathToTab(); // eslint-disable-line react/no-direct-mutation-state
    }

    componentWillUpdate() {
        setTimeout(() => {
            let newTab = this.pathToTab();
            this.setState({
                activeTab: newTab
            });
        }, 1);
    }

    pathToTab() {
        let newTab = 0;

        this.props.children.forEach((tab,index) => {
            let match = matchPath(this.props.location.pathname, {
                path: tab.props.path || "/",
                exact: tab.props.exact || false
            });
            if(match) {
                newTab = index;
            }
        });

        return newTab;
    }

    changeHandler(id, event, tab) {
        this.props.history.push(tab.props['data-path'] || "/");
        this.setState({
            activeTab: id
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Tabs
                    style={{height: '64px'}}
                    contentContainerStyle={{height: '100%'}}
                    tabItemContainerStyle={{height: '100%'}}
                    onChange={(id,event,tab) => this.changeHandler(id,event,tab)}
                    value={this.state.activeTab}
                >
                    {this.props.children.map((tab,index) => {
                        return (
                            <Tab
                                key={index}
                                value={index}
                                label={tab.props.label||""}
                                data-path={tab.props.path||"/"}
                                style={{height: '64px', width: '100px'}}
                            />
                        );
                    })}
                </Tabs>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const CustomTabs = withRouter(CustomTabsImpl);
```

Comment: Can you post small snippets of your code to understand your problem more clearly ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, thanks for replying to your very question.
I have approached this question differently, I decided to post here for the community appreciation.

My reasoning here was: "It would be simpler if I could tell the *Tab* instead the *Tabs* component about which one is active."

Accomplishing that is quite trivial, one can do that by setting a known fixed value to the *Tabs* component and assign that very value to whatever tab is supposed to be active.

This solution requires that the component hosting the tabs has access to the props such as location and match from react-router as follows

---

Firstly, we create a function that factory that removes bloated code from the render method. Here were are setting the fixed Tabs value to the Tab if the desired route matches, other wise I'm just throwing an arbitrary constant such as Infinity.

```html
const mountTabValueFactory = (location, tabId) => (route) => !!matchPath(location.pathname, { path: route, exact: true }) ? tabId : Infinity;
```

---

After that, all you need is to plug the info to your render function.

```html
render() {
   const {location, match} = this.props;
   const tabId = 'myTabId';
   const getTabValue = mountTabValueFactory(location, tabId);

   return (
     <Tabs value={tabId}>
       <Tab
         value={getTabValue('/route/:id')}
         label="tab1"
         onClick={() => history.push(`${match.url}`)}/>
       <Tab
         value={getTabValue('/route/:id/sub-route')}
         label="tab2"
         onClick={() => history.push(`${match.url}/sub-route`)}
       />
     </Tabs>
   )
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use react routers NavLink component

```
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';

<NavLink
  activeClassName="active"
  to="/foo"
>Tab 1</NavLink>
```

When /foo  is the route then the `active` class will be added to this link. `NavLink` also has an `isActive` prop that can be passed a function to further customize the functionality which determines whether or not the link is active.

https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/NavLink

Comment: This won't work. Check out this: http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/tabs The `Tab` components are managed by the parent `Tabs`, and the active tab is changed by changing it's `value` prop.